# initializing state in react-redux on typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I'm trying to initialize store using initState. My initstate object is,

```
const initState :any = {
    squares: Array<number>(9).fill(null),
    curState: false
}
```

I'm creating store like this.

```
let store = createStore(appReducer, initState);
```

This throws an error in typescript saying

> TS2339: Property 'fill' does not exist on type 'number[]'.

My tsconfig.json file

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react",
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

If I change the initState declaration to

```
const initState :any = {
    squares: Array<number>(9),
    curState: false
}
```

then it works, but doesn't create an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "es2015.core" to your tsconfig.json's `lib` property:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es5",
            "scripthost",
            "es2015.core",
        ]
    }
}
```

Note that if the `lib` property isn't specified, like in your original example, the default value of this property is `["dom", "es5", "scripthost"]`.  As a result, you'll also need to add these values to avoid removing these default libraries.

Here's the documentation for the `lib` compiler option: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html (scroll down to `--lib`).

Answer (score 0):

Use array spread to create a new array and then fill each value with null. This should be be valid.

```html
const initState: any = {
    squares: [...new Array(9).fill(null)],
    curState: false,
};
```